# Move matched line above a different matched line using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have something like

```
dsadjakldjska
safdsfdsfsf
fdsfsf**STGN**fdsfsd
fdsfkjldsf
fdsff
fdsfs**IRV**fdsfs
```

and I want to get

```
dsadjakldjska
safdsfdsfsf
fdsfkjldsf
fdsff
fdsfsf**STGN**fdsfsd
fdsfs**IRV**fdsfs
```

but only for an interval of lines (say line 40000 till end of file) (moving the line containing STGN right above the next IRV underneath it)

Any idea how I can do this, or whether there's a better alternative for this than sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR < 40000 {print; next}
     /\*\*STGN\*\*/ {line = $0; next}
     /\*\*IRV\*\*/ && line {print line; line=""}
     {print}'
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '40000,$!b' -e '/\*\*STGN\*\*/{h;d;}' -e '/\*\*IRV\*\*/{x;/./p;s/.*//;x;}'
```

(they assume the STGN occurs *before* the IRV).

Comment: For my own education, what is the reason to use `{x;/./p;s/.*//;x;}` rather than the apparently simpler `{x;G;}`?

Comment: @steeldriver That's so as not to insert the hold space if it's empty (if no STGN was found) and to reset it to the empty string for the next occurrence. That's the equivalent of the `&& line` and `line = ""` in the `awk` one. If there's only one STGN and only one IRV and they occur in that order, then `{x;G;}` works just as well.

Comment: What if STGN occurs *after* IRV?